# A simple mathematical equation does not work in C programming

Tags: c

The following equation gives error message but it should not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a;
   a=12 + 10/2 + 3*2 – 5;
   printf("a=%d",a);
   return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you have copied pasted the code from elsewhere. In expression

```
a=12 + 10/2 + 3*2 – 5;  
                  ^ is not minus sign
```

Change it to `-`

Answer (score 8):

You wrote a dash `–` instead of a hyphen `-`. Spot the difference:

```
... 3*2 – 5;
... 3*2 - 5;
```

Comment: The real question should be why we have to use a hyphen to indicate "minus" :-S

Answer (score 3):

In your expression that's not a minus sign, judging by eye it's an en-dash, which is not accepted by the compiler. Don't write code in Word or "normal" word processors, use plain text editors.

Comment: +1 for further diagnose about usage of word processors